# How control advice catches exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, controller-advice

I am trying to understand how ControllerAdvice is working in SpringBoot. It is suggested that for per application there should be one ControllerAdvice. But my question is how this ControllerAdvice is tied to Controllers and catching the exceptions. So basically what is the underhood?

Answer (score 0):

> Spring AOP works with proxies.

That is when you `annotate` a class with any of `AOP annotation` `spring` will create a `proxy class` by `extending` your annotated class and all the methods will be overridden there in the proxy class.

Thus here after when you call a `method` in `your class` spring will call the `proxy object method` first then your `actual method`. This is `Spring AOP` knows whether the `method has been called` or `thrown some exception` or `returned successfully` etc etc.

[image]

This is the reason why when you call a `private method` with in the `class` `AOP` cannot `intercept` that method call.

Comment: So, is it correct that Spring registers classes annotated with @ ControllerAdvice and @ Controller as beans and consider every methods annotated with @ RequestMapping(and its shortcut annotations) as Pointcuts even though there is no explicit @ Pointcut on methods annotated with @ ExceptionHandler in @ ControllerAdvice?